# How to remove underscore('_') along with preceeding digits in first columns only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to  remove  underscore('_') with associated digits after it.
This is the first row in my text file.

```
JP_001033692.1_551  N   -1  NO  99.5425%    0.0022875
```

I would like to remove "_551" from  "JP_001033692.1_551" without  removing other  items from the subsequent columns.

Expected row would be:

```
JP_001033692.1  N   -1  NO  99.5425%    0.0022875
```

Here is my code:

```
fname = open(raw_input('Enter input filename: '),'r' )
outfile = open('decValues.txt','w')

for line in fname:
    line = re.sub('[\(\)\{\}\'\'\,<>]','', line)
    fields = line.rstrip("\n").split()
    outfile.write('%s  %s %s  %s %1.4f\n' % (fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],fields[3],(float(fields[5]))))
```

Thanks guys for helping out.
Kesh

Comment: Are all of these places that you want to remove the underscore following numbers after a decimal point?  If so you could search for the appropriate decimal points.

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort, Bozhidar Batsov. It worked for all types in my text file. You've  just my saved my day. I'm very grateful to everyone who  provided some  form of solution to my problem. Thanks alot.Keep the good work, guys. Cheers, Kesh.

Comment: @user587646 If his answer worked, you should mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
re.sub(r"(\.\d+)_\d+", r"\1", line)
```

Comment: It works with the line you've shown in you question. I'm not sure what's not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

str.rpartition(sep)¶ will split the string on the last occurance of sep

> > > s = "this_is_a_string"
> > >
> > > split_s = s.rpartition('_')
> > >
> > > split_s

('this_is_a', '_', 'string')

> > > split_s[0]

'this_is_a'

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
re.sub("(?P<x>(_.*)?)_\w*","\g<x>",str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
re.sub(r'^([^ ]*)(_[0-9]*)( +)', r'\1\3', line)
```

Test from the Python repl:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = 'JP_001033692.1_551  N   -1  NO  99.5425%    0.0022875'
>>> re.sub(r'^([^ ]*)(_[0-9]*)( +)', r'\1\3', line)
'JP_001033692.1  N   -1  NO  99.5425%    0.0022875'
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it only works for this specific. I have tons of these types of lines. The value after the underscore ranges from 0-9. This is Nathan's approach should have  removed  it from all, but it didn't. What's  the 'r' and r'\1\3'?

Comment: @user587646 Can you give more line examples?

Comment: r"" signifies a raw string - useful for regex